# Unable to create wifi hotspot .. even kde is not working .. all this happened after updating in 15.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, kde

When I click the connect to hidden wifi network , It has stopped to show the list of all hotspots I previously connected to, So i tried to check in settings->network->use as hotspot, Even this failed . I also tried with kde5-nm-connection-editor, This worked perfectly before the update, but now even it is not working .. I tried to start a hotpsot in my friends laptops .. Even they are not working :\

Comment: Try reinstalling kde on your system.
It worked for me
Hope it works for you too :)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Problem is partially solved , Now i am able to create a hotspot, but there is no response after i click on Connect to hidden networks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in 15.10. Creating a normal wifi connection first using Network Manager and then changing the `mode` to `ap` in the corresponding configuration file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<wifi-hotspot>` makes it work. (Replace  with the name of your connection)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for responding . I have tried all the 3 methods in that link and all of them failed . I have even changed infrastructure -> ap mode even then there is no change .